# Encrypting media files for firebase storage

Tags: node.js

I am trying to have users  store videos, Images to firebase storage but I want them to be fully encrypted and can only be accessed by the user who uploaded/sends the content.

I try to use Google's KMS to encrypt the data, save the encrypted data  as base64 string but I found that doing so easily becomes a problem because of the problems that arise from storage that way.

With that said, is there a way for users to store encrypted images and video using Google's KMS  to firebase storage with NO one else including the Firebase project admins having no access to the plaintext content?

Here is a part of my client side flutter code to send a photo as bytes to the cloud function for encryption:

```
final encryptdata = FirebaseFunctions.instance.httpsCallable(
        'encryptMessageAndStore');
final fileBytes = await photo?.originBytes;
      final data = {
        'photo': fileBytes,
        'sender': senderId,
        'receiver': receiverId,
        'time': DateTime.now().toIso8601String(),  
      };

      result = await encryptdata.call(data);
```

This is the corresponding part of the nodejs, typescript function that I currently have that stores encrypted data to firebase:

```
if (data.photoote != "null") {
        messagedocumentID = data.documentID;
        const mediaBuffer = Buffer.from(data.photo, "base64");
        const payloadCrc32c = crc32c.calculate(mediaBuffer);
        const [fileResponse] = await kmsClient.encrypt({
          name: keyName,
          plaintext: mediaBuffer,
          plaintextCrc32c: {
            value: payloadCrc32c,
          },
        });

        if (!fileResponse.verifiedPlaintextCrc32c) {
          throw new functions.https.HttpsError("internal", "Encrypt:"+
        "request corrupted in-transit");
        }

        // Check that ciphertext is not null or undefined
        if (!fileResponse.ciphertext || !fileResponse.ciphertextCrc32c) {
          throw new functions.https.HttpsError("internal",
            "Encryption failed. No ciphertext was returned.");
        }
 
        encryptedphoto = Buffer.from(fileResponse.ciphertext)
          .toString("base64");




        const photo = {"photo": encryptedphoto};

        await admin.firestore().collection("messages").
          doc().set(photo);

      }
```

Could storing the data as bytes significantly lower storage? If so how can i do?

Any help on this is fully appreciated. Thanks!